# In VueJS, is it good practice to have some component templates in HTML and some templates in PUG / Jade?

Tags: html, pug, frontend, vue.js

Since Vue's component based architecture keeps division of labor in mind, is it a good idea to allow some developers to write templates in HTML and some in PUG as they see fit? Or should all developers be instructed to stick to the same language?

What are some drawbacks to allowing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would make more sense for everything to be in the same language. It means everyone in the company follows 1 style and there's no need to look up syntax if someone is unfamiliar with PUG / HAML etc. It's always better to follow 1 consistent rule.

Obviously you could choose PUG / HAML to be your main choice but whatever you choose all components should be written in the same style and language.